# javacv for with android

Tags: android, javacv

i'm working on android app that create video from list of images  using javacv i did all the following :

## Follow the instructions on this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/

# Go to File > New > Folder, select your project as parent folder, type "libs/armeabi" as Folder name, and click Finish.
 # Copy `javacpp.jar` and `javacv.jar` into the newly created "libs" folder.
 # Extract all the `*.so` files from `javacv-android-arm.jar`, `opencv-2.4.8-android-arm.jar`, and `ffmpeg-2.1.1-android-arm.jar` directly into the newly created "libs/armeabi" folder, without creating any of the subdirectories found in the JAR files.
 # Navigate to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click "Add JARs...".
 # Select both `javacpp.jar` and `javacv.jar` from the newly created "libs" folder.

but i still have this error UnsatisfiedLinkError  can you tell me what is the problem?
i also tried making new project but the same error!

Comment: no , every time i try to download it i keep getting Network error , is it necessary to use NDK ?

Comment: And one more thing, *.so files put inside of "jni" folder instead of "lib//armeabi" folder.
Then compile using NDK then *.so files generated inside of "lib/armeabi" folder

Comment: thanks, is there another link to download NDK beside this one: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing

Comment: You do not need NDK if you are using JAVA-CV. Its a wrapper for OpenCv!

Answer (score 0):

check your build.gradle file, it should contain:

```
dependencies {
  [...]
  //JavaCV
  compile files('libs/ffmpeg.jar')
  compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
  compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
  compile files('libs/opencv.jar')
  compile files('libs/armeabi.jar')
  compile files('libs/javacv-android-arm.jar')
  compile files('libs/opencv-android-arm.jar')
  compile files('libs/ffmpeg-android-arm.jar')
}
```

I think your gradel file is missing javacv-android-arm.jar, opencv-android-arm.jar, libs/ffmpeg-android-arm.jar.